# AC Power Balance Equation

Tags: power, ac

For the example on Page 7 of this lecture:

https://www.keithmoffat.com/IntrEPS/IntrEPS_Lecture11_PowerFlow.pdf

quoted here:

[image]

Are the following balance equations correct?

$$
1=-10 sin \delta_{11}+10|V_2|sin \delta_{12}
$$

$$
Q_1=10cos \delta_{11}-10|V_2|cos \delta_{12}
$$

$$
300M=10|V_2| sin \delta_{21}-10|V_2|^2 sin \delta_{22}
$$

$$
100M=-10|V_2|cos \delta_{21}+10|V_2|^2 cos \delta_{22}
$$

where
$$
\delta_{ij}=\delta_i - \delta_j
$$

$$
|V_1|=1, \delta_1=0, P_1=1
$$

If so, then the answers given by this slides which are
$$
\delta_2 = -0.3
$$
and
$$
|V_2|=0.9
$$

are not correct.  Why? Thanks !

Comment: You may get more response if you copy the example into your question rather than expect people to look up an external reference.

Comment: @GrahamNye Thanks.  Added it there now.

Comment: @GrahamNye could you help? I'd appreciate

Comment: I'm afraid I've already given you my best tip. Sorry it didn't actually help. Despite the name of this forum it tends to lean towards electronics and microcomputing and is rather short of power engineers. My own experience with the power side only runs to wiring up low voltage computer peripherals (at 415 V).